# Using jQuery, find all selects and append the index value as options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find all `<select>` elements on my page, take an index, then append each index as a value to all select's `<option>`. Here I have each select:

```
<select class="select"></select>
<select class="select"></select>
<select class="select"></select>
<select class="select"></select>

var i = 0;
  $(".select").each(function(){
    ++i;
  });
  $(".select").each(function(){
    for (i > 0){
      $(this).append("<option val='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
    }
});
```

In the end, the goal I'm trying to achieve will have each select looking like:

```
<select>
  <option val="1">1</option>
  <option val="2">2</option>
  <option val="3">3</option>
  <option val="4">4</option>
  <option val="5">5</option>
  <option val="6">6</option>
  <option val="7">7</option>
  <option val="8">8</option>
  <option val="9">9</option>
  <option val="10">10</option>
</select>
```

It looks like I'm almost there...

Comment: What should your `i` do?

Comment: Ya know, `each` comes with its own index param

Comment: @BlueSkies I made a mistake and left off the class="select" in the final snippet. That isn't a requirement but I see you got my intention in your answer. Each select should look like the final example I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $selects = $("select");
var selCount = $selects.length;

for(var i=1; i<=selCount; i++){
    $selects.append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wy643/

Comment: This is what I was getting at in my own code. I guess I was wrong to assume I could simply use i > 0 and be done with it. I don't see why, but ok. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If every select should get as many options as there are total selects, then yuo can just do this:

```
var sel = $("select")
sel.map(function(i, s) {
     return $("<option>", {text: i, value: i})[0];
}).appendTo(sel);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/vmUpN/

---

Here's a plain JS version if you're interested.

```
var sel = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var opts = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    opts.appendChild(new Option(i, i));
}
for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].appendChild(opts.cloneNode(true));
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/vmUpN/1/